# Forest loss by Hansen Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I noticed something when the forest loss model was applied by Hansen (2000-2021 )/In Arabian Gulf countries such as Saudi Arabia, UAE and Oman, data can be represented on the chart until 2014 only. While in other countries such as Egypt, Morocco and Nepal, representation and data are provided until 2021.

Does this mean that there has been no forest loss in these countries since 2014?

The code I used for a country from the Arabian Gulf (Saudi Arabia)
https://code.earthengine.google.com/33ac26eb895369a4ee569e8be213b99d

The same code I used for another country only changed the name of the state and got representation by badge until 2021
https://code.earthengine.google.com/f85859774391b9210423f15c9e7c43c3

Comment: Please add the code from the code environments to the post with an edit. Not everyone has access to the Code Editor and the links can disappear over time.